# What is a PHP method for multiple inheritance? - excellent

Tags: php, oop, class

I have a class that needs access to two other classes.  `Signin` needs access to `Post`, and `Signin` needs access to `Database`. How do I do this?

I had previously made the inheritance chain linear, but this seems to confuse people as a `Post` is not a `Database`.

Comment: Have you seen about `traits`? Looks like you it may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not have multiple inheritance (as I think you understand already).  If you cannot make a linear inheritance chain, another option is create and implement an interface:

```
class Child_Class extends Parent_Class implements Brother_Interface {}
```

However, that doesn't seem to fit your situation either.

For your needs, it my be appropriate to pass the `Database` object and the `Post` objects into the `Signin` object via dependency injection. After all, is `Signin` really an extension of `Database`?  Is it an extension of `Post` (maybe). Dependency injection may be a more appropriate OO methodology here.

```
class Signin {
  private $db;
  private $post;

  public function __construct($post, $db, $othervariables...) {
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->post = $post;

    // Rest of constructor
  }
  // Access via $this
  public function something_using_db() {
     $this->db->execute("SELECT * FROM tbl;");
  }
}
```

How it is used:

```
$db = new Database();
$post = new Post();

// Create Signin object using the Database and Post    
$signin = new Signin($post, $db);
```

Comment: This is what I want to do...but I don't understand your example...what are you passing in the contructor?...What is $db and what is $post..what are you passing in...are you instantiating outside of the class...and passing in the object reference?

Comment: @stack.user.0 See addition above. This assumes you have Database and Post objects for each of those class es. They are passed into the Signin constructor

Comment: thanks I'm likely going to break the Liskov substituion principle...but may later switch tod dependency injection...thanks for the good info.